# Css stop div from expanding upwards into another div

Tags: html, css

I have created a website with a navbar and I now wanna add another div under the navbar

I only want the div to expand downwards and not into the navbar itself

How do I ensure that my main div can only expand downwards and if need be expand the body?

Please note that the issue will only arrise when there is large content within the div

```css
.main {
  margin: 2dvh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(41, 143, 233);
  min-width: 80dvh;
  max-width: 150dvh;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100dvh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1dvh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div style="justify-content: space-evenly;display:flex;">
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your navbar is overlapped by the main div? And would like the main div to go after it and take the full height of the viewport if necessary?

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion

Comment: The full height part is a bit tricker, you can probably do that with `calc`

Comment: I just want it to expand downwards instead of upwards maybe I phrased that wrong im very sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the absolute positioning that you have in the `main` div. I just removed it and add `margin: auto` to center it.

```css
body {
  height: 100dvh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  margin: 2dvh auto;
  background-color: rgb(41, 143, 233);
  min-width: 80dvh;
  max-width: 150dvh;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1dvh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div style="justify-content: space-evenly;display:flex;">
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
      <a class="navelement">
        <u><h2>navelement</h2></u>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
</body>
```